# Fitting an ARMA model to a return series when series fails Ljung heteroskedasticity test(significant coefficients)

Tags: r, time

so I'm working with a generic log return series, which I made independent by modeling it as an ARMA(1,1) process. Now the resduals fail the Ljung test, i.e. the squares of residuals do not show any heteroskedasticity. However, on failing to find a way to model the residuals as a t-distribution (ARIMA does not allow t setting), I tried to model the residuals as an ARCH(1) process, with all coefficients significant at the 5% level (this allowed me to model the error as t distribution too)

1. Is it correct to go ahead with ARCH model in this case?
2. Is there any reason why this is happening?